# how to implement variable length argument function in scala

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, variable-length

I have to concatenate `k`  different lengths of strings into one string `res` and save `res` string into `ArrayBuffer[String]()`. 
But the `k` is variable.
For example,

```
val result = new ArrayBuffer[String]()
result.+=("1\t" + A.toString() + "\t" + ls.pid + "\t" + ls.did + "\t" + ls.sid + "\t" + ls.request_time.substring(0,10))

result.+=("2\t" + B.toString() + "\t" + ls.pid + "\t" + ls.did + "\t" + ls.sid + "\t")

result.+=("2\t" + B.toString() + "\t" + ls.pid + "\t" + ls.did + "\t")

result.+=("2\t" + B.toString() + "\t")
```

How to use a function with a variable-length argument to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```scala
def f(args: String*) = {
    args.map{s =>
    //todo: process single item
    s
  }
}
```

Comment: I would just add the note that `String*` means is just a `Seq[Sring]` inside the method body so OP can do anything you can do on a sequence, like `map` or `foldLef` or `foreach`, etc.